# "Forbidden" when trying to install free widget for Magento 1.8

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm new to Magento.I have installed Magento 1.8.0.1 and have added sample data.

Now page in localhost likt this,

[image]

Now I want to [add some free widgets](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ma2-widget-slideshow.html), when click install now button, it shows get extension key, so copy that link and run in browser, but it displays:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /community/Ma2_Slideshow_Free/ on this server.

May I know, if I did these steps correct or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below step to install your required widget/extension

- go to Adminpannel -> System -> Magento Connect -> Magento Connect Manager.
- Login with your adminpannel "username" & "password"
- select your key from http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ma2-widget-slideshow.html
- Paste that key in Magento Connect Manager page :/ Paste extension key to install:  -> Click install
- Every time when you install a new extension, make sure u have to logout of your adminpannel & login again respectively to aspect your new changes made.

Don't forget to clear cache from System -> Cache Management

Comment: let the cmd commads to execute, And logout after you get installed Successfully msg

Comment: @SELVA - after you paste extension key in your magento connect manager -> then click install . So, is there any process seen there ?? or getting error msg or anything..?? pls paste your screen shot..?? or give some more detail

Comment: http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Ma2_Slideshow_Free

paste above link in your magento connect manager-> then click install -> if again u get same error then follow below step:
_ open - http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php
- paste your link here & get that extension as in .zip format

Comment: @SELVA : might be missing some firefox add on / try clear firefox cache ctrl+shift+delete / also logout/login your magento admin & clear your magento cache

Answer (score 0):

Please go to `System >> Magento Connect >> Magento Connect Manager`, a window will open to validate the user, you have to login. A new page will open, find `Paste extension key to install` and paste your key in the text box, then click the `Install` button. It will again ask you to proceed click the proceed button and the module will be installed.

Comment: after that what to do, i done as you told, but nothing happen in my home page..

Comment: do you see the cmd commands running when u proceed?